# Jenkins build error FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, compiler-errors

I started using Jenkins 2.73.1 on Windows 7.
I also have Apache Maven 3.5.0 installed at C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin.
In Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration, I defined the maven installation.

I defined MAVEN_HOME as C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin, but it gives me a warning message
"C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin doesn’t look like a Maven directory".

I leave the setting as is because that is the correct maven install directory.
Should the path be something else?

I proceed with the project build and I get this error.

FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

What doesn't make sense is that I believe I have the correctly configured the Maven install so I don't know why I get the warning message and the error.

After searching online some seems to indicate that it is looking for mvn.cmd or mvn.bat so I made a copy to have both files in the directory but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

I defined MAVEN_HOME as C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin, but it should be MAVEN_HOME as C:\apache-maven-3.5.0.

This worked for me.

ikask